# Android get notified when Content Provider Image database get updated

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to get notified about the changes in content provider Image database. 
So whenever this database is updated I want my sqlite database to get updated accordingly.
And I want to get notified on Content provider image database getting updated event if my application is not running.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ther's a method called `update()` in content provider class. Override this method. this method will be called whenever user updates something to the content providers database. So in the body of `update()` method write your code for updating your SqlLiteDatabase. If you want to know more about contentprovider method please check this url http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

ThankYou.

Comment: But how to do that in background process. When activity is not running

Comment: if you want to do it in background use services

Comment: I think the method update() in content provider is to manually update content of database. Whereas I want to get notified when this database is updated

Comment: Update in contentprovider will be called whenever user calls Contentresolver.update() . contentprovidr can only be updated using contentresolver. so if you want to do things like you said. you should probably write your code in update() method

Comment: I think I am still not convinced. I simply want to make notification on notification bar whenever the Image Media database is updated.